# Xamarin.iOS: Share file sheet appears only for two seconds

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Xamarin.Essentials provides a mechanism to share a local file. The typical use case:

```cs
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = "Sharing a file...",
    File = new ShareFile(pathToLocalFile),
});
```

`pathToLocalFile` - contains absolute path to local file that has to be shared.

While this code works perfectly for Android, on iOS it does not work as expected.

**On iOS "Share file" sheet appears only for a couple of seconds and just disappears.**

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the [Xamarin.Essentials sample](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Share/Share.ios.cs), related to this functionality, and I came to the following conclusions.

`ShareFileRequest` class has `PresentationSourceBounds` that should be set to the bounds of the `parent` view element.

"Share file" functionality should be called from a visible view element, for example via clicking a button on the page. Calling this functionality from a menu item does not work.

So, I've created a page, and in page xaml, declared the button like that:

```xml
<Button Text="Click here to share the file..." 
        Command="{Binding ShareLocalFileCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

In the page view model I declared `ShareLocalFileCommand` this way:

```cs
public Command<View> ShareLocalFileCommand { get; }
```

In the view model constructor I've initialized `ShareLocalFileCommand` property like this:

```cs
ShareLocalFileCommand = new Command<View>(ExecuteShareLocalFileCommandAsync);
```

And the relevant method has been implemented like that:

```cs
private async void ExecuteShareLocalFileCommandAsync(View viewElement)
{
    await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
    {
        Title = "Sharing local file...",
        File = new ShareFile(LocalFilePath), // LocalFilePath contains path to local file to be shared
        PresentationSourceBounds = GetAbsoluteBounds(viewElement)
    });
}


private static System.Drawing.Rectangle GetAbsoluteBounds(View element)
{
    Element looper = element;

    var absoluteX = element.X + element.Margin.Top;
    var absoluteY = element.Y + element.Margin.Left;

    while (looper.Parent != null)
    {
        looper = looper.Parent;
        if (looper is View view)
        {
            absoluteX += view.X + view.Margin.Top;
            absoluteY += view.Y + view.Margin.Left;
        }
    }

    return new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)absoluteX, (int)absoluteY, (int)element.Width, (int)element.Height);
}
```

Please note, between your click on the button and calling `await Share.RequestAsync()` there should not be any view elements that appear and disappear, like confirmation dialogs, etc etc. Otherwise `viewElement` parameter will be passed as `null`.